# Can't save custom array to database

Tags: arrays, cakephp-2.0

I built a data array from various sources, and then want to save it to a table in a database. All the fields are correct when I debug the array:

```
array(
    'KmLibrary' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'km_file_id' => (int) 5910,
            'title' => 'Guide Tax Season 2012 Afrikaans',
            'author' => 'SARS',
            'book_number' => '213',
            'isbn' => '23523626235425',
            'category' => 'Blue',
            'keywords' => 'Some keywords'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'km_file_id' => (int) 5911,
            'title' => 'Tax season 2012 insert',
            'author' => 'SARS',
            'book_number' => '235',
            'isbn' => '329062806306',
            'category' => 'Red',
            'keywords' => 'Nothing to report'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'km_file_id' => (int) 5912,
            'title' => 'Source Codes',
            'author' => 'SARS',
            'book_number' => '462',
            'isbn' => '23562362354',
            'category' => 'This',
            'keywords' => 'Boobs'
        )
    )
)
```

However, when I use the command `$this->KmLibrary->saveAll($data);` OR `$this->KmLibrary->save($data);` it just adds an empty record to the database.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Kekekeke, only saw now what was in the sample data I tested with... It's late in the day here, please excuse that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue. Read [here](http://blog.alexnj.com/cakephp-saveall-with-multiple-records-not-saving-anything.html) for a properly discussed and dumbed down answer.